# Azure CLI keeps stripping a character

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I am running the following command, give or take.

```
az webapp config appsettings -set --name myappservice --resource-group myresourcegroup --settings mysetting="@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://mysecretuir)"
```

The final ) in the settings gets stripped every time.  I have even tried to escape that character and it still gets stripped.  Does anyone have any recommendations on how to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ^^ can escape the character, found in this in the comments on this github item.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/7147